# Player doesn't move when "Apply root motion" is turned off

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, gravity, rigid-bodies

I'm working with a game involving slopes and i tried to have movement with physics.Velocity.... however i think animator's root motion causes player to land slowly after jumps or after simple landing and the physics effects aren't that good in that case.

I tried disabling the root motion but that causes the player to be stuck at a particular position.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: You are giving almost Zero information about what you are working with...
Is this Unity3D, do you have some screen shots or code snippets?
Help us help you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, i solved this on my own. By removing curves under animation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).